# How to save reyclerview's scroll position?

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview

In activity1, I used recycler view to store images downloaded from firebase. When an image is clicked, activity2 is opened to show description of image. How to store scroll position of activity1(when i click on up button in act2, it has to go to previous scroll position in act1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store `firstVisiblePosition` from `LayoutManager` of `RecyclerView`

```
firstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)rv.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

or

Store the clicked position.

Then, `registerReceiver` with an instance of `BroadcastReceiver` using `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadCastListener, filter)` in Activity1

And send a message using `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)` from Activity2

Increment the value of `firstVisiblePosition` when you get a callback in `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive`

Finally in `onResume`

```
((LinearLayoutManager) rv.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(firstVisiblePosition);
```